# How do I know why a wheel is not supported on a platform?

Tags: pip, python-wheel, pycairo

I'm trying to install Cairo (a 2D graphics library). I've not used any `.whl` before (at least not manually) and I don't understand the error message I'm getting. I downloaded `pycairo-1.18.2-cp38-cp38-win32.whl` and tried to `pip3 install` it but I get the following error:

`ERROR: pycairo-1.18.2-cp38-cp38-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

As far as I know I have the correct version of the wheel since my Python is

`Python 3.8.0 (tags/v3.8.0:fa919fd, Oct 14 2019, 19:21:23) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32`

The command I used to get this error was

`pip3 install [full path to the .whl file in my Downloads]`

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong here? [Here's](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pycairo) where I downloaded the wheel file from. (There are other options too but I believe I got the correct one.)

EDIT1:

> Installing Pycairo requires pkg-config and cairo including its
>   headers.

Now looking into how to get those...

Comment: `cp38-win32` means it's a wheel for CPython 3.8 for 32-bit Python. You showed us your Python is 3.8, but is it 32-bit? `python -c "import struct; print(struct.calcsize('P') * 8)"`. And what about `pip`? `pip3 --version`.

Comment: `python -c "import struct; print(struct.calcsize('P') * 8)"` printed `32` and `pip3 --version` printed `pip 19.3.1`. Also, I got the issue solved (see EDIT1). Turns out I just wasn't aware what pycairo truly was; I didn't have the actual Cairo software thing in my system which pycairo would rely on. Missed one level there. Thanks though!

Answer (score 6):

***Update***:

With recent versions of pip, one can call `path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip debug --verbose` and it should print the list of compatible tags (among other things) for that Python interpreter.

---

> How do I know why a wheel is not supported on a platform?

Some technical details regarding the *Python wheel tags*:

- The document that defines the current standard: [PEP 425 -- Compatibility Tags for Built Distributions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0425/)
- An in-depth study: [Brett Cannon's "The challenges in designing a library for PEP 425 (aka wheel tags)"](https://snarky.ca/the-challenges-in-designing-a-library-for-pep-425/)
- The library that handles it in *pip*: [documentation page for `packaging.tags`](https://packaging.pypa.io/en/stable/tags/)

Assuming you have the project [*packaging*](https://pypi.org/project/packaging/) installed, you can get the list of all *wheel tags* that are supported by your environment with the following:

```
python3 -c "import packaging.tags; print(list(packaging.tags.sys_tags()))"
```

Comment: @AravindSuresh This should print something, I don't know what is different in your setup. With recent versions of pip, one can call `python -m pip debug --verbose` and it should also print the list of compatible tags (among other things), maybe you could give this a shot

Comment: seems that the problem was that I hadn't installed `packaging` yet. It works now.